# How to log response status log in postman

Tags: javascript, testing, postman, assertion

How do I console the response status code in Postman ?

I have this snippet here:

```
pm.test("Status code is 200", function () {
pm.response.to.have.status(200);
});
```

I want to log response status code 200 if I get it.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
console.log(pm.response.code)
```

you can get it from pm.response object in test script section

Comment: Yep, that's how I would do it - More details for the other `pm.*` API methods  https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/script-references/postman-sandbox-api-reference/

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to the Tests tab:

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);

console.log(jsonData.code);
```